# How to use omniplot with python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

While searching of a solution I think I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210640/how-can-i-draw-a-nested-pie-graph-in-matplotlib-in-python/75742812#75742812), but unfortunately I can't import it to Jupyter Lab. I think I have to install the module, but didn't found anything about it with Google search. I followed the hyperlink the user gave, but don't know how to use the website. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct version of Python, run the following in a new cell in your JupyterLab:

```py
%pip install git+https://github.com/koonimaru/omniplot.git
```

Then restart the kernel and try the import statement.
That is based on [here](https://github.com/koonimaru/omniplot#install) and modern Jupyter having the `%pip install` command that allows you to run installations in the notebook and get installation to the correct environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Presently, Python version 3.11.3 is not supported. You'll get an error when installing:

```py
RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.11.3; only versions >=3.7,<3.11 are supported.
```

If you need a place where the installation is already handled for comparison, go [here](https://mybinder.org/) and put in `https://github.com/koonimaru/omniplot` in the top line in the form, below 'GitHub repository name or URL' and click 'Launch'. At present the session that comes up has a compatible version of Python and packages already installed.

If you run it elsewhere, I found in most cases I also had to update seaborn by running the following in the notebook and then restarting the kernel:

```py
%pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

The code you link to [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75742812/8508004) runs where I say 'the installation is already handled' above. (I assume it works; I'm not sure it is what it should look like. But it runs without error.) Only the bottom example [here](https://github.com/koonimaru/omniplot#example-usage) runs. The top example fails with `TypeError: nested_piechart() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ncols'`. ( I believe I even tried `%pip install git+https://github.com/koonimaru/omniplot.git@dev` and the top example still failed.)

---

You should be able to make a nested donut plot directly in Matplotlib, see [donut_plots_with_subgroups here](https://github.com/fomightez/donut_plots_with_subgroups) that uses Matplotlib under-the-hood and adds some features to make providing the exact settings for a nested donut plot easier. (If you want to try it out, presently the launch button doesn't **temporarily** work because the MyBinder people are adjusting something. There is a work around for now though, and so you can go [here](https://mybinder.org/) and put in 'https://github.com/fomightez/donut_plots_with_subgroups' where it says 'GitHub repository name or URL' and then press the 'launch' button to launch a session with the demo notebooks present.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I'm using Python 3.9.16 .
I tried to install omniplot with your given code. Unfortunately I got an error:

ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: Now I installed git, updated conda and then tried to install omniplot with your given code.
This doesn't work and produced error:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyrle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for sorted_nearest, pyrle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: You'd have to look into why that package and particular version it is trying to install doesn't work on your system. I'm not familiar with that package myself. Omniplot is an very complex installation as it installs a lot of things, many of which may be unnecessary for what you are trying to accomplish. That is why a more direct route to do what you want may be better. On the other hand, an alternative solution would be to remotely use a system where installation works as it should.